# Convert excel database to a reproducible format

Tags: r

Sorry if the question is simple!

I have an excel database, .xlsx format. However I wanted to convert it to the `df <- structure(list(.......)` format so it's playable for you. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Are you just asking how to import an xlsx file in R? There are several packages that do that (xlsx, openxlsx, readxl all come to mind)

Comment: I would like to turn my database into a reproducible example. How can I do this? For example, I can insert from my database into a repository to be downloaded, what are the other solutions?

Comment: Are you just looking for the reprex guidance? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
dput(df)
```

One way could be with `readxl`:

```
install.packages("readxl")

library("readxl")

my_data <- read_excel("my_file.xls")
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is a way for me to read the file of excel, right. But I would like to make a reproducible example for you of this database, so what are the ways I can show this my database to you? I thought about transforming it into `df <- structure(list(.......)`

Comment: `dput(my_data)`?

Comment: It was `dput` even what I needed. Thanks!